# SQL server stores date minus 1 hour

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I do an update on a database record. For a date field I send this value:

value   "12/30/2018 12:00:00 AM"

It's an ajax post where I fill a parameter. In debug the parameter looks like this:

```
Name blaat 
Type varchar (I also tried Datetime)
value 12/30/2018 12:00:00 AM
```

No errors but when I look in the database this is stored:

"2018-12-29 23:00:00.000"

To convert the date I use javascript "toLocaleString"

```
function toDate(dateStr) {
    const [day, month, year] = dateStr.split("-")
    var d = new Date(year, month - 1, day)
    return d.toLocaleString();
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: show your code here

Comment: @mhsankar Done!

Comment: Never use `VARCHAR` for `DATETIME`.  You didn't include the code that you execute to store the data in the db

Comment: I'm getting a bit closer to the actual problem. My Azure sql database is using UTC (i cannot change that). I'm located in holland so I have UTC + 1. So what is the best way to solve this issue? When I do a conversion in my application?

Comment: If you're storing dates, and you have different timezones, then you have 2 legitimate options: 1 store all times on the server as UTC and have your application change the time. 2: use `datetimeoffset` and pass the as part of your time to your data engine. Then, again, use your application to display the appropriate time for the timezone you're in.

Comment: Thanks for your help